# Cached plugin issue while working with load balancer

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a grails application with enabled grails cache and  zipped resource plugin. We have multiple deployments of the war behind a load balancer.
When try to access the application there seems some of the images are missing. This is our problem.
When we tried to access the image directly pointing to the servers with out load balancer one server contains the image and other one doesn't contains . why this happens?
I think All the images are not created in the work folder while startup of the server. I saw that there is files count are different in two server image work folders that was defined using the  grails.resources.work.dir.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem w/ images using Grails 2.1, Tomcat 7, and F5 load balancer.  It was because sessions were not being correctly managed between the multiple grails app deployments.  This caused 302 redirects of images (from /images to /static) to fail because they were split between two different servers.  We were able to solve the problem by enabling sticky-sessions / session affinity in the load balancer to ensure all requests go to the same server once a session is established.  Not sure if you are experiencing the same issue, but it might be worth a try?